# Insert if not exist C# SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to add datatable if the data is not existing before

```
public async Task saveBetEntity(List<BetEntity> betList)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // dt.Columns.Add("ItemId");
    dt.Columns.Add("Player_no");
    dt.Columns.Add("PLAYER_BET_NUMBER");

    dt.Columns.Add("BET_PLACED_DATE");
    dt.Columns.Add("OVER_1000_SEK");
    dt.Columns.Add("EVENT_NAME");
    dt.Columns.Add("LEAGUE");
    dt.Columns.Add("BET_OFFER_TYPE");
    dt.Columns.Add("CRITERIA_NAME");
    dt.Columns.Add("IS_LIVE");
    dt.Columns.Add("BET_LABEL");
    dt.Columns.Add("ODDS");
    dt.Columns.Add("BET_OUTCOME");

    if (betList != null && betList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in betList)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Player_no"] = item.Player_no;
            dr["PLAYER_BET_NUMBER"] = item.PLAYER_BET_NUMBER;
            dr["BET_PLACED_DATE"] = item.BET_PLACED_DATE;
            dr["OVER_1000_SEK"] = item.OVER_1000_SEK;
            dr["EVENT_NAME"] = item.EVENT_NAME;
            dr["LEAGUE"] = item.LEAGUE;
            dr["BET_OFFER_TYPE"] = item.BET_OFFER_TYPE;
            dr["CRITERIA_NAME"] = item.CRITERIA_NAME;
            dr["IS_LIVE"] = item.IS_LIVE;
            dr["BET_LABEL"] = item.BET_LABEL;
            dr["ODDS"] = item.ODDS;
            dr["BET_OUTCOME"] = item.BET_OUTCOME;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string InsertQuery = string.Empty;
            InsertQuery =
                "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BetEntities  WHERE Player_no =dt.Rows[i][\"Player_no\"].ToString()   BEGIN" +
                "INSERT INTO BetEntities " +
                "(Player_no, PLAYER_BET_NUMBER, BET_PLACED_DATE, OVER_1000_SEK, EVENT_NAME," +
                " LEAGUE, BET_OFFER_TYPE, CRITERIA_NAME, IS_LIVE, BET_LABEL, ODDS, BET_OUTCOME) " +
                "VALUES ('" + dt.Rows[i]["Player_no"].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["PLAYER_BET_NUMBER"].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["BET_PLACED_DATE"].ToString()
                + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["OVER_1000_SEK"].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["EVENT_NAME"].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["LEAGUE"].ToString() +
                "','" + dt.Rows[i]["BET_OFFER_TYPE"].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["CRITERIA_NAME"].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["IS_LIVE"].ToString() +
                "','" + dt.Rows[i]["BET_LABEL"].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["ODDS"].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i]["BET_OUTCOME"].ToString() + "')" +
                " WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM BetEntities WHERE Player_no =dt.Rows[i][\"Player_no\"].ToString()" +
                "  AND PLAYER_BET_NUMBER = dt.Rows[i][\"PLAYER_BET_NUMBER\"].ToString()  " +
                "  AND BET_PLACED_DATE =dt.Rows[i][\"BET_PLACED_DATE\"].ToString()" +
                " AND OVER_1000_SEK =dt.Rows[i][\\\"OVER_1000_SEK\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                 " AND EVENT_NAME =dt.Rows[i][\\\"EVENT_NAME\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                  " AND  LEAGUE =dt.Rows[i][\\\" LEAGUE\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                   " AND BET_OFFER_TYPE =dt.Rows[i][\\\"BET_OFFER_TYPE\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                    " AND CRITERIA_NAME =dt.Rows[i][\\\"CRITERIA_NAME\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                     " AND  IS_LIVE =dt.Rows[i][\\\" IS_LIVE\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                      " AND BET_LABEL =dt.Rows[i][\\\"BET_LABEL\\\"].ToString()\"" +

                       " AND  BET_OUTCOME=dt.Rows[i][\\\" BET_OUTCOME\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                ");";

            using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionAPIConeectionString")))
            using (var BetEntities = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, destinationConnection))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();
                BetEntities.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The code works fine if I delete

```
" WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM BetEntities WHERE Player_no =dt.Rows[i][\"Player_no\"].ToString()" +
                        "  AND PLAYER_BET_NUMBER = dt.Rows[i][\"PLAYER_BET_NUMBER\"].ToString()  " +
                        "  AND BET_PLACED_DATE =dt.Rows[i][\"BET_PLACED_DATE\"].ToString()" +
                        " AND OVER_1000_SEK =dt.Rows[i][\\\"OVER_1000_SEK\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                         " AND EVENT_NAME =dt.Rows[i][\\\"EVENT_NAME\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                          " AND  LEAGUE =dt.Rows[i][\\\" LEAGUE\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                           " AND BET_OFFER_TYPE =dt.Rows[i][\\\"BET_OFFER_TYPE\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                            " AND CRITERIA_NAME =dt.Rows[i][\\\"CRITERIA_NAME\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                             " AND  IS_LIVE =dt.Rows[i][\\\" IS_LIVE\\\"].ToString()\"" +
                              " AND BET_LABEL =dt.Rows[i][\\\"BET_LABEL\\\"].ToString()\"" +

                               " AND  BET_OUTCOME=dt.Rows[i][\\\" BET_OUTCOME\\\"].ToString()\"" +
```

I don't want to add the data over and over, that's why I added this code.

Comment: Use parameters. Never ever write SQL queries like this. You were lucky it didn't work. BTW your code is a mess written like that. Why wouldn't you simply use verbatim strings instead? That way it would be much easier to test your code in SSMS too.

Comment: Is this something that is done on a one-time basis, or a regular basis?  If the former, make it a more orthodox part of your DevOps process.  If the latter, consider using a different data structure like EAV that can be *user-defined.*  Arbitrary, ad-hoc changes to database structure seldom works out well.

Comment: If you were to write this as a verbatim string you would also see why it doesn't work. It wouldn't actually work with or without that part you said it works without.

Answer (score 1):

You have many errors in your code.

First error is related to not using verbatim string. Without a verbatim string, your SQL Command is a mess and and it is very hard to see the basic errors there that would cause a syntax error on the SQL server side and wouldn't execute at all. You said it works if that "where" didn't exist, but your code is already erroenous without it.

Next there is error from T-SQL point of view if you didn't miss a single quote or double quote and wrote the command string perfectly correct. Your command would conceptually look like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM BetEntities WHERE Player_no ... )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BetEntities 
       ( Player_No, ... ) VALUES ( 1, ... )
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select ... )
END;
```

However this is invalid T-SQL syntax. You can't use

> ... VALUES (...) WHERE

To overcome that limitation, you just need to change the syntax a bit and move that "NOT EXISTS" check to the "IF NOT EXISTS" check at top. That is what you are doing after all.

Third error is the one that you might have passed if you put all those + single and double quotes right in your code and that would be a guaranteed disaster in future if not today. You were lucky, indirectly it didn't work and you are here. As I said in comments, **never ever write an SQL command like that concatenating strings and putting user inputs within that.** That is because:

- It makes your SQL code wide open to bad things, widely known as **SQL Injection Attack**.
- Many users get away ignoring the **use parameters** saying, thinking it is only for SQL Injection Attacks and their code is never open to a real user input from outside or they think they are *sanitizing* it with some way (well hackers know ways against sanitization if I do know as one mere coder). However, it doesn't only prevent SQL Injection Attack but also take care of the formatting of input values themselves. For datetimes for example, if you were passing it as a string (don't), then it should be in a specific format in order to be independent of server settings. Or with a string, if the string itself contained quote or double quote (ie: O'Hara, 24" pipe) then it would fail or be interpreted in a very different way, although it was an innocent query.

You decide which one of the above reasons are more important in order to use parameters, but at the end I repeat:

**Never ever write an SQL command like that concatenating strings and putting user inputs within that.**

(I even have a tendency to write that in capitals:)

Then comes another question, why would you ever need a DataTable in between? Directly use the list itself.

> A side note by the way, with a list or DataTable or whatever (like
> json, xml, ...), if there are many rows to write, then instead of a
> loop, you would surely want to do this with the SqlBulkCopy class or
> T-SQL Bulk copy or using JSON, XML ...

OK, having said all these, here is a revised version of your code with parameters and verbatim string. You can see the difference in readability at least:

```
public async Task saveBetEntity(List<BetEntity> betList)
{
    if (betList == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    string insertQuery = @"IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM BetEntities
    WHERE Player_no = @Player_no
          AND PLAYER_BET_NUMBER = @PLAYER_BET_NUMBER
          AND BET_PLACED_DATE = @BET_PLACED_DATE
          AND OVER_1000_SEK = @OVER_1000_SEK
          AND EVENT_NAME = @EVENT_NAME
          AND LEAGUE = @LEAGUE
          AND BET_OFFER_TYPE = @BET_OFFER_TYPE
          AND CRITERIA_NAME = @CRITERIA_NAME
          AND IS_LIVE = @IS_LIVE
          AND BET_LABEL = @BET_LABEL
          AND BET_OUTCOME = @BET_OUTCOME
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BetEntities
    (
        Player_no, PLAYER_BET_NUMBER, BET_PLACED_DATE,
        OVER_1000_SEK, EVENT_NAME, LEAGUE,
        BET_OFFER_TYPE, CRITERIA_NAME, IS_LIVE,
        BET_LABEL, ODDS,BET_OUTCOME
    )
    VALUES
    (@Player_no, @PLAYER_BET_NUMBER, @BET_PLACED_DATE, 
    @OVER_1000_SEK, @EVENT_NAME, @LEAGUE, 
    @BET_OFFER_TYPE, @CRITERIA_NAME, @IS_LIVE, 
    @BET_LABEL, @ODDS, @BET_OUTCOME);
END;
";
    using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionAPIConeectionString")))
    using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, destinationConnection))
    {
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Player_no", SqlDbType.Int);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@PLAYER_BET_NUMBER", SqlDbType.Int);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@BET_PLACED_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OVER_1000_SEK", SqlDbType.Text);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EVENT_NAME", SqlDbType.Text);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LEAGUE", SqlDbType.Text);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@BET_OFFER_TYPE", SqlDbType.Text);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CRITERIA_NAME", SqlDbType.Text);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IS_LIVE", SqlDbType.Bit);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@BET_LABEL", SqlDbType.Text);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ODDS", SqlDbType.Text);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@BET_OUTCOME", SqlDbType.Text);


        destinationConnection.Open();
        foreach (var item in betList)
        {
            insertCommand.Parameters["@Player_no"].Value = item.Player_no;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@PLAYER_BET_NUMBER"].Value = item.PLAYER_BET_NUMBER;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@BET_PLACED_DATE"].Value = item.BET_PLACED_DATE;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@OVER_1000_SEK"].Value = item.OVER_1000_SEK;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@EVENT_NAME"].Value = item.EVENT_NAME;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@LEAGUE"].Value = item.LEAGUE;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@BET_OFFER_TYPE"].Value = item.BET_OFFER_TYPE;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@CRITERIA_NAME"].Value = item.CRITERIA_NAME;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@IS_LIVE"].Value = item.IS_LIVE;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@BET_LABEL"].Value = item.BET_LABEL;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@ODDS"].Value = item.ODDS;
            insertCommand.Parameters["@BET_OUTCOME"].Value = item.BET_OUTCOME;
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Note: I made guesses on the real SqlDbTypes. Reality might be different, and your list content might not be checked already (ie: It may contain a string value for something that is DateTime or a number, I skipped checking things like that which you should control with TryParse, if that is a possibility. With proper Lists it shouldn't be).

Answer (score -3):

You will need to do it as you were doing before, otherwise, you are sending a string that SQL does not interpret:

Instead of this:

```
" WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM BetEntities WHERE Player_no =dt.Rows[i][\"Player_no\"].ToString()" +
```

Do this for each value from the datatable:

```
" WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM BetEntities WHERE Player_no = " + dt.Rows[i]["Player_no"].ToString() +
```

Comment: Never ever write SQL queries like this. Use parameters.

Comment: For the billionth time. NOBODY should write answers to Sql questions if they don't know what Sql Injection is and how to avoid it